# lapply with two column arguments

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

These is my dataframes

```
library(data.table)
df <- fread('
            Account       Date        NextDate
            A          2016-01-01     2016-02-01
            A          2016-02-01     2016-11-05
            B          2016-03-10     2016-11-05')


ab <- fread('
      Date       Amount
     2015-06-01     55
     2016-01-31     55
     2016-02-28     65
     2016-03-31     75')
```

I want to create a list by doing a loop as of each row in `df` and pick all rows from `ab` where `ab$Date` is greater than `df$Date` and less than `df$NextDate` so that the output looks like this:

```
[[1]]

Date       Amount
2016-01-31 55

[[2]]

Date        Amount
2016-02-28  65
2016-03-31  75

[[3]]
Date        Amount
2016-03-31  75
```

This is my attempt:

```
list<- lapply(df$Date, function(x,y) br[Date > x & Date < y ],y=df$NextDate)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a vector that checks whether rows of `ab` meet your conditions, then use it to select rows of `ab`.

```
lapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) {
  ab[which(ab$Date > df[x, get("Date")] & ab$Date < df[x, get("NextDate")]), ]
})
```

Comment: You're welcome. You can thank me better by upvoting and selecting my answer!

Answer (score 3):

You can use apply:

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) ab[ab$Date>x[2] & ab$Date<x[3],])
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible this is not truly in the dataframe traditions, but I think the logic is fairly clear if you are coming from a base-R background. The data.table "[" function needs to have unquoted column names in a list to delive just column values:

```
apply( df[, list(Date,NextDate)] , 1, 
       function(dts)  ab[ ab$Date > dts['Date'] & ab$Date < dts['NextDate'],  ])
[[1]]
         Date Amount
1: 2016-01-31     55

[[2]]
         Date Amount
1: 2016-02-28     65
2: 2016-03-31     75

[[3]]
         Date Amount
1: 2016-03-31     75
```